# WPF NavigationWindow and StatusBar

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

Is it possible to have a StatusBar in a WPF application that runs a NavigationWindow, other than by including it on each Page hosted by the navigation window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, overriding NavigationWindow template does the trick:

```
<NavigationWindow  x:Class="Test.NavWindow"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   Title="NavWindow">
    <NavigationWindow.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationWindow">
            <DockPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Label Content="StatusBar..." 
                       Background="LightGray"
                       DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
            </DockPanel>            
        </ControlTemplate>
    </NavigationWindow.Template>
</NavigationWindow >
```

It's just demonstration, usually you should perform better tweak of ControlTemplate, thank's god you could find a lot of examples over internet.

Comment: Having said that, the navigation chrome at the top of the NavigationWindow have disappeared (although the navigation functions are still available via keyboard defaults). Is it possible to keep the navigation buttons from the default template, while adding in the status bar, or do I need to re-implement the navigation buttons, since I'm providing my own content template?

Comment: I suppose, yes, you should reimplement buttons.